Is there a way to numerically find multiple minima of a function?
So I have a function f(θ) that I can calculate numerically on a range 0 to 2pi. (specifically the minimum distance between the point on one keplerian orbit and another keplerian orbit).
I know from experiments that the function has one or two (or infinite) minima.
Using golden section search I can find one of these minima, but if there is another it would be good to know of that one as well.
Naively I could split up the range into sections, find the minima in each and hope the two minima are in different sections, but is there a better way?

I think that a question about mathematics would be more suitable for https://math.stackexchange.com/ because here as long as the function is numeric the answer you may get is just brute force all possible values

Just out of head - you may calculate your function with step (say 1 deg = Pi/180) and compare values. If next value is higher then previous  that means you passed local minimum. And you would need to check if function valuese were going down before minimum.

I would suggest a variation on golden section search, but unfortunately the question has been closed.

Close-voters, can you explain your reasons for closing? This question is literally asking for an algorithm to solve a problem, yet the closing message says "This question does not appear to be about a specific programming problem, a software algorithm, or software tools primarily used by programmers."

As far as I know, there is really nothing better to do than sample at a number of points (randomly or deterministically) and then search on each subregion. How many points are needed depends on the maximum second derivative of the function (assuming it's smooth; if it's not smooth, nothing short of exhaustive evaluation can work). Try drawing your function, then mark some points on it, and pretend you're searching on those intervals. Now draw some very large wiggles. How can you be sure you found all the wiggles? This is the problem you are up against.

"Naively I could split up the range into sections, find the minima in each and hope the two minima are in different sections" << How would that work? Imagine you have a section [a,b] and you select two points x1, x2 inside the section for the golden search. If you're lucky and get f(a) > f(x1) < f(x2) < f(b) then you can safely  conclude that there is a local minima in interval [a, x2]. But if you're unlucky and get f(a) < f(x1) < f(x2) < f(b), you can conclude nothing.

@Stef I was clear since the beginning on why I voted to close the question. If you are vague enough to describe your function in terms of "I have a function f(θ) that I can calculate numerically on a range" to me it means those are "random" data points and you cannot express it in algebric terms as to perform the derivative approach. When you say numeric and you don't further specify, the only answer you can receive is traverse the entire domain (brute force). And by the way it's about mathematics not algorithm.

by the way since the domain is Real I guess it makes sense to approach it in a different way than what I suggested .. I was out of touch with the domain of this problem

Without an actual description of the kind of function(s) you're dealing with, there is no general algorithm. If you know there are two minima, at the very least remember to explain how you know that: what concrete problem are you working on, what shape does your function have based on what you've seen so far, what code did you already try/write to solve it, and where/how did those attempts fall short of a desired solution? Hit the [edit] link, and please update your post to include all the currently missing details.

Indeed this should not have been closed as off-topic, as numerical finding of minima is certainly a programming problem. However, it is too broad. There is substantial literature on it, too much to cover in a Stack Overflow question. The question ought to be at least reduced to the specific case at hand.

Kepler orbits are well-behaved functions; they are not going to have crazy swings that present numerical difficulties unless they have bizarre orbital parameters. Once you have found one minima m0, what happens if you then partition the domain into everything below that ([0, m0)) and everything above it ((m0, 2π]) and search those?

(Do note that two orbits can have up to four minima in their distance function, so rephrasing this question explicitly as "I have two orbits and am trying to numerically find the minima of the distance function between them" with actual code to show what you already tried, to make sure this is a programming question and not a pure maths question, would make this a much better question, especially as future visitors with the same problem will be more likely to find it in a search)
